# Countdown timer in Javascript - Conditional Timing

Tags: javascript

I'm making a countdown timer for the curfew timing of my hostel (8.30 pm). It resets every day, however, I want it to reset at 5 am each day. From 8.30 pm to 5.00 am, I would want it just to give the output as 'Curfew'.

```js
var start = new Date;
start.setHours(20, 30, 0);
function pad(num) {
  return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
}
var now = new Date;
setInterval(() => now = new Date);
function tick() {
  if (now > start) {
    start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
  }
  var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
  var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
  var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
  var ss = pad(remain % 60);
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = hh + ":" + mm + " hours";
  setTimeout(tick, 60000);
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", tick);
var cstart = new Date; // Curfew start
start.setHours(20, 30, 0);
var cend = new Date; // Curfew end
start.setHours(5, 0, 0);
if ((now > cstart) && (now > cend)) {
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Curfew";
}
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Would something like this be the right approach?

Comment: `now = new Date` ... Surely you don't expect me to wait until 5am to reproduce your problem.  :/

Comment: There's an edge case with doing `new Date;` multiple times - you may get different dates for `now`, `cstart` and `cend` if this code runs very nearly just before midnight.  Also `(now > cstart) && (now > cstart)` seems a little fishy, doesn't it?  You're checking the same condition twice.

Comment: I've been 'debugging' by changing the times of `cend`. Please advise on how to go about this. I've declared `now` in the 6th line.

Comment: You don't use `cend` in your code.

Comment: Why are you setting the time on `start` twice in a row?  `start.setHours(20, 30, 0);` then immediately do `start.setHours(5, 0, 0);`  Proofread your code, and step through it with a debugger.  These are careless typo-style mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (hh > 15 && mm > 30){
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "Curfew in order. It ends at 5.00 AM";
} else {
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "Time until curfew: " + hh + ":" + mm + " hours";
setTimeout(tick, 60000);
}
```

Using `hh` and `mm` conditions, I was able to have conditional outputs!